# Facebook not using native app to login. But Only some times

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm having an issue with the facebook ios sdk. I've set the facebook login manager to use native. It detects the app is installed but then this method

```
- (BOOL)_useFeatureWithKey:(NSString *)key dialogName:(NSString *)dialogName {
    if ([dialogName isEqualToString:FBSDKDialogConfigurationNameLogin]) {
        return [(NSNumber *) (_dialogFlows[dialogName][key] ? : _dialogFlows [FBSDKDialogConfigurationNameDefault][key]) boolValue];
    } else {
        return [(NSNumber *)(_dialogFlows[dialogName][key] ? : _dialogFlows [FBSDKDialogConfigurationNameSharing][key] ? : _dialogFlows [FBSDKDialogConfigurationNameDefault][key]) boolValue];
    }
}
```

returns NO and this is caused because the variable *userNativeFlow* in `FBSDKServerConfigurationManager.m` is set to NO using

```
BOOL useNativeFlow = ![FBSDKInternalUtility isOSRunTimeVersionAtLeast:iOS9Version];
```

Does someone know something about this? I do not want to hammer the Pod and force it to return *YES*

Thanks.

Comment: did you get the answer ? please share ?